# Need help setting up ndb.StructuredProperty for One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am creating an application using Python (2.7) and GAE.  I am trying to create a one-to-many relationship.  There is one client with numerous properties which also has many potential contacts. Contacts also has various properties.  The example of using the [ndb.StructuredProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured) seems pretty straight forward, but when I import my data model with a structured property line, I keep getting the following error in my log:

NameError: Name 'Contact' is not defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**main.py**

```
from dataObjects import *
```

**dataObjects.py**

```
class Client(ndb.Model):
    createDate = ndb.DateProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    address1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    address2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    state = ndb.StringProperty()
    zipCode = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone = ndb.StringProperty()
    fax = ndb.StringProperty()
    website = ndb.StringProperty()
    city = ndb.StringProperty()
    industry = ndb.StringProperty()
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    notes = ndb.StringProperty()
    financing = ndb.StringProperty()
    contacts = ndb.StructuredProperty(Contact, repeated=True)

class Contact(ndb.Model):
    firstName = ndb.StringProperty()
    lastName = ndb.StringProperty()
    role = ndb.StringProperty()
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone = ndb.StringProperty()
    fax = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    createDate = ndb.DateProperty()
    isClient = ndb.StringProperty()
    address = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: Because it's not defined yet. Swap the order of the models.

Comment: That simple?  What a noob!  Worked like  a charm.  Thanks for the super speedy response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) pointed out :

"Because it's not defined yet. Swap the order of the models."

Basically, when creating the model Client, your code needs a Contact object. Since Contact doesn't exist for your code, it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for cases when its not possible to just change the order of definition you can add a property after the model were defined (that includes self-referencing):

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  pass

User.friends = ndb.StructuredProperty(User, repeated=True)
User._fix_up_properties()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap the order of the 2 models as when you defined the Client model the Contact model is not defined.